# Gps notification iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, location

Is there any api in iPhone sdk for getting the major change in location (ie for more than 500m). I need to notify the user even though the application run's in background.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on the running in the background part, but iOS 4.0 introduced some major change in location monitoring to CLLocationManager, specifically 'startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges'. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered in detail in this document: [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://goo.gl/Zq00k)